# How to view broken picture link in a website?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to retrieve certain images within a website, but some of them are unavailable.

I have attempted page refresh, browser switching, and wait-some-days-and-try. Still not working.

There is cached website service in Google. What about cached picture or similar service?

Comment: Use the wayback machine to see a snapshot in time for that website...https://archive.org/web/

Answer (score 1):

This started out as a comment but grew too big.

Generally if an image on a website is broken the fault lies with the website host not with your computer. There are a few things you can try from your side though:

- You can try disabling any advert blocker tools in your browser. If the site uses an image cache service this can be a different url. Some caching services are known to host spam images and the ad blocker will block these images even if they are legitimate.
- Do a forced refresh. I know you have said you have already refreshed the page multiple times, I am only including this option for completeness. A forced refresh will fetch a brand new copy of the page from the server. Hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and click the reload button on the browser toolbar.
- Check on the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) as [@Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab) suggested to see if the site has been trawled and cached.
- The images could have been relocated or removed completely from the site. You can try viewing the source code in the browser developer tools to see if the image url has an obvious typo in it then manually going to the correct url but this is really clutching at straws.
- You might want to try contacting the site owner, they may have made a mistake and accidentally broken the image link and not know it. This is especially true on larger sites where it is difficult for someone to manually check every page (there are automated processes to help with this but describing them is out of scope for this answer). Personally this is the option I would try first.

Without seeing the page in question myself I can't advise further.